# Trouble deriving the general formula of complex trigonometric functions where $z \in \mathbb C$ is the argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have successfully derived the equation $\sin(y)=\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}$ and its corresponding cosine partner $\cos(y)=\frac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{2}$ **where $y \in \mathbb R$**.

In my book, the general equation for $z \in \mathbb C$ (of the form $z = x+yi$) is also provided for sine and cosine functions:

$$\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

$$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

I am having some difficulties deriving these equations. **I'll show what I have so far for $\cos(z)$**.

At the outset, note that $e^{ik}$ where $k \in \mathbb R$ is defined to be equal to $\cos(k)+\sin(k)i$

Firstly, we see that $e^{i*z}$ can be rewritten as $e^{i*(x+yi)}$, which is equal to $e^{-y+xi}$.

$$e^{-y+xi} = e^{-y}e^{xi} = e^{-y}(\cos(x)+\sin(x)i)$$

In a similar fashion, we know that $e^{-i*z}$ can be written as $e^{-y-xi}$.

Following a similar set of steps, $e^{-y-xi} = e^{-y}(\cos(-x)+\sin(-x)i)$

Recall that $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$. Therefore we have:

$$e^{-y}(\cos(-x)+\sin(-x)i) = e^{-y}(\cos(x)-\sin(x)i)$$

---

If we then add  $e^{-y+xi}$ to $e^{-y-xi}$ we get:

$$e^{-y+xi} + e^{-y-xi}=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+\sin(x)i) + e^{-y}(\cos(x)-\sin(x)i)$$

$$e^{-y+xi} + e^{-y-xi}=2*e^{-y}\cos(x)$$

Reverting back to our initial definitions of $z$ and $-z$ we have:

$$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2*e^{-y}\cos(x)$$

$$e^{-y}*\cos(x) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

**And this is where I am completely stuck**. The only thing I can think to do is make the following statement:

$$\cos(z) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} e^{-y}*\cos(x)$$

But that seems sort of hand wavy to me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First of all, what's your definition of $\sin(z),\cos(z)$ when $z\in\Bbb{C}$? Is it using the power series?

Comment: The problem is that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are defined only on the real axis. You are going into circles because you try to prove something about $\cos(z)$ without having a definition of it. What is $\cos(z)$?

Comment: The first chapter of Rudin's "Real & complex analysis" has a nice accessible section on the exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove something about $\cos(z), \sin(z)$ you need first to define $\cos(z), \sin(z)$.

The formulas you are trying to prove are the usual definitions.

Alternatelly, you can prove the following result:

**Lemma:** There exists an unique entire function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that
$$f(x) = \cos(x) \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

Moreover,
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \forall z \in \mathbb C$$

**Proof** Existence follows from the fact that $\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} $. Uniqueness follows from the identity theorem for Analytic functions.

\qed

The above Lemma, allows you to alterately define $\cos(z)$ as the unique entire extension of $\cos(x)$ and derives the identity you want.

You can prove a similar result for $\sin(z)$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Out of curiosity then, if this is a definition, is there an initial motivation for defining $\cos(z)$ in that fashion? (i.e. I assume there are many other functions that can also reduce to the $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$ formulas $ \forall y \in \mathbb R$...so why this one in particular?)

Comment: @S.Cramer There are of course infinitely many ways to extend a function (just define it arbitrarily outside the initial domain of definition). But, as mentioned in the answer, there is a **unique** way to extend the function to $\Bbb{C}$ such that the new extended function is entire (i.e it is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}$; i.e it is complex differentiable at every point of $\Bbb{C}$, or equivalently such that it is analytic on all of $\Bbb{C}$)

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{i z}-e^{-i z}}{2i}$ and $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{i z}+e^{-i z}}{2}$.